# Solving a question using characteristic function where X is discrete and Y is continuous

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, binomial-distribution, characteristic-functions

$X = Binom(5,0.5)$ and $Y=U(0,1)$. we need to find $P(X+Y \geq2)$

using characteristic function. This is what I could solve but could not go ahead.

$C_X(t)=\frac{(e^{it}+1)^5}{2^5}$

$C_Y(t)=\frac{e^{it}-1}{it}$

Taking $Z=X+Y$ and since both X and Y are independent.

$C_Z(t)=C_X(t)C_Y(t)= \frac{(e^{it}+1)^5(e^{it}-1)}{2^5\cdot it}$

After this what should I do, integration would not be feasible.

Comment: Do you _have_ to use characteristic functions, e.g, because that is what your homework demands, or are other methods acceptable?

Comment: Only characteristic function. Other method i have got

Comment: Someone Please help.